# Showing next hidden div and Hiding current shown div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am setting up a navigation structure for a survey with next and previous buttons. I am loading all the html from separate files into the `index.html` file and storing each file in separate `divs`. Then when someone clicks next it hides the current div and shows the next div. I have this working if I hard code the name of the div inside the buttons but I want an easier way to navigate. I figured I would use the `next()` and `prev()` with jQuery so that if I want to restructure the layout I don't have to go in and re do the names in all the separate files. Below is my structure inside my `index.html` file :

```
    <div class="Page" id="DealerInfo" style="display: block;">
            <script>$( "#DealerInfo" ).load( "formPages/DealerInfo.php" );</script>
    </div>

    <div class="Page" id="AdditionalLocations" style="display: none;">
        <script>$( "#AdditionalLocations" ).load( "formPages/AdditionalLocations.php" );</script>
    </div>

    <div class="Page" id="OwnerInfo" style="display: none;">
        <script>$( "#OwnerInfo" ).load( "formPages/OwnerInfo.php" );</script>
    </div>
```

Here is my function for showing the next div but it will not set the `display: block` to just the next div it sets it for all of them. You can see that

```
function nextPage() {
    $( "div" ).prev(".Page").css( "display", "none" );
    $( "div" ).next(".Page").css( "display", "block" );
}
```

This is how I call it on the first DealerInfo page:

```
<p class="navigation"><button class="button" type="button" onclick="nextPage();">Next</button></p>
```

If you notice `DealerInfo` is the first Div shown with `display: block` set, and all of the other divs below it are set to `display: none`. When the user clicks next it should set `DealerInfo` `display: none` and set `AdditionalLocations` `display: block` I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Could you please set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ba7Au/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("div")` selects all divs and thus `.next()` will fetch the next element for each div. Also you probably want to hide the current div and not the previous. And I'd also recommend using `show()` and `hide()` instead of setting display.

I suppose you want something like:

`$(this).hide().next(".Page").show();`

### Edit

`$(this)` needs to be the currently shown page, it depends on the details not shown in your example. For embedded forward buttons in each its something like `$(this).parents(".Page")` while for one fixed forward button its rather like `$(".Page:visible")`.

Edit

for http://jsfiddle.net/Ba7Au/2/
$(".Page:visible").hide().next(".Page").show();

Comment: This seems to not work in my case I copied it into my fiddle posted in the comments under the question and the button does not seem to respond

Answer (score 1):

Your code `$( "div" ).next(".Page").css( "display", "block" );` calls the `.next` function on each div, so it ends up showing every div after the first one. (Similarly, the `$("div").prev(".Page")` code hides every div except the last one, though that doesn't affect you since they were already hidden.) You need to specify which div you want to start from. The easiest way for that is probably to add a class with a name like **active**.

```
<style>
    .Page { display: none; }
    .active { display: block; }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.button', function() {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').next('.Page').addClass('active');
    });
});

<div class="Page active" id="DealerInfo">
        <script>$( "#DealerInfo" ).load( "formPages/DealerInfo.php" );</script>
</div>

<div class="Page" id="AdditionalLocations">
    <script>$( "#AdditionalLocations" ).load( "formPages/AdditionalLocations.php" );</script>
</div>

<div class="Page" id="OwnerInfo">
    <script>$( "#OwnerInfo" ).load( "formPages/OwnerInfo.php" );</script>
</div>

<p class="navigation"><button class="button" type="button">Next</button></p>
```

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jlansner/HdAXC/